# Diagonal entries of an inverse M-matrix fall as we remove matching rows and columns of original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $N\times N$ strictly substochastic matrix (i.e., $a_{ij}\in[0,1)$ and $\sum_{j}a_{ij}<1$), let $B=I-A$, and let $\tilde{B}$ be the matrix obtained from $B$ by removing the first row and the first column. Finally, let $M$ be the adjugate matrix of $B$ and $\tilde{M}$ be the adjugate matrix of $\tilde{A}$. For $N=3$ below I show that $$\frac{\tilde{M}_{22}}{\mathrm{det}\tilde{B}}\leq\frac{M_{22}}{\det B}.$$ Note that this implies that the $(2,2)$ entry of $\tilde{B}^{-1}$ is weakly lower than the corresponding entry of $B^{-1}$. Does this result generalize to $N>3$? In the proof below I only use that $B$ has positive diagonal and negative off-diagonal terms, so I think this is a property of all M-matrices.

In the case in which $N=3$ then
$$
\tilde{M}_{22}=1-a_{33}
$$
$$
\det\tilde{B}=\left(1-a_{22}\right)\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{23}a_{32}
$$
$$
M_{22}=\left(1-a_{11}\right)\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{13}a_{31}
$$
$$
\det B=-a_{31}\left(a_{12}a_{23}+a_{13}\left(1-a_{22}\right)\right)+a_{32}\left(-\left(1-a_{11}\right)a_{23}-a_{13}a_{21}\right)+\left(1-a_{33}\right)\left(\left(1-a_{11}\right)\left(1-a_{22}\right)-a_{12}a_{21}\right)
$$
so we need to show that
\begin{align*}
-a_{31}\left(1-a_{33}\right)\left(a_{12}a_{23}+a_{13}\left(1-a_{22}\right)\right)+a_{32}\left(1-a_{33}\right)\left(-\left(1-a_{11}\right)a_{23}-a_{13}a_{21}\right)+\left(1-a_{33}\right)^{2}\left(\left(1-a_{11}\right)\left(1-a_{22}\right)-a_{12}a_{21}\right)\\
\leq\left(\left(1-a_{22}\right)\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{23}a_{32}\right)\left(\left(1-a_{11}\right)\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{13}a_{31}\right)
\end{align*}
Eliminating matching terms on both sides leads to
$$
-a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}\left(1-a_{33}\right)-a_{12}a_{21}\left(1-a_{33}\right)^{2}\leq-a_{13}a_{23}a_{31}a_{32}
$$
which obviously holds.

How do I extend this proof for $N>3$? One possibility I see is to use this result here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250091/165163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, a direct implication of Theorem 3.5 (i) in Johnson and Smith's Inverse M-matrices, II here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2011.02.016

Let $C$ be an $N \times N$ matrix, let $\emptyset \neq \alpha \subseteq \{1,...,N\}$, and let $C[\alpha]$ be the matrix that results from $C$ after removing the rows and columns in $\alpha$. The theorem states $$\left(C^{-1}[\alpha]\right)^{-1} \leq C[\alpha],$$ where the inequality is entrywise.

Setting $C = B^{-1}$ and $\alpha = \{1\}$, the theorem implies that all the elements of the inverse of M-matrix $\tilde{B}$ are weakly lower than the corresponding elements of the inverse of M-matrix $B$.